# A question about $3$-smooth differences between primes

Tags: prime-numbers, computational-mathematics, conjectures

There are an infinite number of primes $p$ such that there are no prime $q<p$ such that $p-q$ is $2$-smooth (a power of two) and the smallest such numbers are $p=2,127,149,...$. https://oeis.org/A065381.

The same idea for $3$-smooth differences yields the question if there are prime numbers $p>2$ such that it doesn't exists a prime $q<p$ such that $p-q$ is $3$-smooth? Due to my tests such a prime is greater than $10^{10}$ if it exists.

I do think there is such a failing prime but that my computation skills and computer systems are too limited to find out.

> Question: is there a failing prime or can it be proved that $3$-smooth differences always exists?

Comment shows there should be a lot of failing primes, but which is the smallest greater than $2$?

---

If $F=\{k\in\mathbb N_{>1} |2^{k-1}\equiv 1\pmod k\}$ one can ask for which $n\in F$ it doesn't exist a $m\in F,\; m<n$ such that $n-m$ is $3$-smooth. For all $n\in \{t\in F | 10^{10}\leq t < 2\cdot10^{10}\}$ there exist one such number $19115108601$, which is not a prime.

---

A big gap from $p$ downwards to previous prime should decrease the probabillity for 3-smooth gaps. I tested all so far known records of gaps

[Prime gaps Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Numerical_results)

without find an exception. So I add the conjecture tag.

Below a diagram of the number of 3-smooth differences as a function of the prime $p$. The red curve is $\ln p$

[image]

Comment: I suspect this is a hard question. The proof that there exists infinitely many primes of the first type relies on a technique called "covering cogruences", so you could try searching to see if that's been applied to $2^k3^\ell$ instead of just $2^k$. There are about $p/\log p$ gaps that could work and $\sim c(\log p)^2$ numbers of the form $2^k3^\ell$ in that range where $c=1/(2\log2\log3)$, so a probabilistic heuristic predicts that a prime has about a $p^{-c}$ chance of failing, suggesting that there should be infinitely many failing primes (since $c<1$).

Comment: I would conjecture that such $3$-smooth differences will *almost always* exist, based on statistical heuristics. Differences between primes of $6, 12, 18, 24, \cdots$ are going to be extremely common, and that list will include a large proportion of the multiples of $6$. It'd be difficult to prove either way though, but I wouldn't bet on finding a counterexample among the known primes.

Comment: @EricSnyder - I think that Greg Martin is right. If testing for differences of the form $2^iq^j,\; q>3$ there are decending smallest failures: $q=5$: $731593$; $q=7$: $8111$; $q=11$: $977$ etc.

Comment: Not sure whether Greg's argument considers the special structure of the numbers $p-S$ where $p>3$ is a prime and $S<p$ a 3-smooth number. I think , for large primes there are many $S$ such that $p-S$ has no small prime factor increasing the chance to find a prime. I tend to believe that there is no counterexample after having tried many random primes in different ranges.

Comment: @Peter - You may be right.

Comment: @GregMartin - Could it be an error in your estimation?

Comment: @Lehs The answer to that question, at that level of vagueness, is always simply "maybe". It would be more productive to ask about particular details of the argument that you think might be inaccurate. Peter suggests some special structure, which is worth asking, but after thinking about it a little I believe that it makes primes in certain residue classes even more likely to be failing primes.

Comment: @GregMartin - I couldn't follow your intusion and it seems that if $f(p)$ is the number om primes $q<p$ such that $p-q$ is-smooth, then $(\ln p)/2<f(p)<3\ln p$.