# A riddle about 3-smooth differences between primes

Tags: prime-numbers, computational-mathematics

You could ask if it for every odd prime $p$ exist a prime $q<p$ such that $p-q$ is $3$-smooth. My investigstions suggests that an exception should be very big, at least greater than $2^{64}$. Define a function $f(p)$ to be the number of primes $q<p$ such that $p-q$ is $3$-smooth (blue dots below).

[image]

It seems to exist lower and upper limits of $f$ of the form
$A\cdot\ln p<f(p)<B\cdot\ln p$ as above, where $A\approx 0.5$ and $B\approx 3$.

Below a table of records for the assumed constants $A,B$. The records occure approximately with doubled intervalls and with capricious leaps. It's possible that the leaps doesn't approach zero (fast enough) and that $A\to 0$ and $B\to\infty$ as $p\to\infty$.
$$
\begin{array}{r|cc}
p & \text{A} & \text{B} \\
\hline
3 & 0.910239226626837 & 0.910239226626837 \\
5 & 0.910239226626837 & 1.24266986911922 \\
11 & 0.910239226626837 & 1.66812956569699 \\
19 & 0.910239226626837 & 1.69811635947554 \\
29 & 0.910239226626837 & 1.78184522624022 \\
79 & 0.910239226626837 & 1.83089494831324 \\
83 & 0.910239226626837 & 2.03673334225281 \\
181 & 0.910239226626837 & 2.11599620695013 \\
199 & 0.910239226626837 & 2.2670147284829 \\
677 & 0.910239226626837 & 2.30143549312477 \\
1607 & 0.910239226626837 & 2.30286014672168 \\
1657 & 0.809414677965558 & 2.30286014672168 \\
2719 & 0.809414677965558 & 2.40262434014324 \\
3761 & 0.728824004123081 & 2.40262434014324 \\
3931 & 0.728824004123081 & 2.53725869996085 \\
12211 & 0.728824004123081 & 2.55045315359463 \\
14753 & 0.728824004123081 & 2.60438322902193 \\
30671 & 0.677567576348398 & 2.60438322902193 \\
43067 & 0.677567576348398 & 2.71777016192333 \\
54287 & 0.642081661528661 & 2.71777016192333 \\
60607 & 0.63566061439303 & 2.71777016192333 \\
88001 & 0.614838505984447 & 2.71777016192333 \\
148549 & 0.614838505984447 & 2.77109027177284 \\
272353 & 0.614838505984447 & 2.79667658660832 \\
348563 & 0.614838505984447 & 2.82096857684845 \\
740681 & 0.591920639360573 & 2.82096857684845 \\
769999 & 0.591920639360573 & 2.87734869685204 \\
1163719 & 0.591920639360573 & 2.93546316868478 \\
6240473 & 0.539593563616334 & 3.13167747560669 \\
20818597 & 0.534081609939492 & 3.13167747560669 \\
42125693 & 0.534081609939492 & 3.13280203029418 \\
*70752683 & 0.534081609939492 & 3.1535791352481
\end{array}
$$

[image]

Above diagram for records of $A$ (blue) and $B$ (red) as function of the primes where the records occured.

> My question is, can someone find records $A<0.5$ or $B>\pi$?

---

A record greater than $\pi$:
$p=70752683\quad B=3.1535791352481$

Comment: For anyone who doesn't know what $3$-smooth means: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number

Comment: Your original question is related to prime gap problems. If there are infinitely many twin primes then your question follows.

Comment: @GarethMa - Can you leave references?

Comment: @Lehs ? if $(p, q) = (p, p + 2)$ then $q - p = 2$ is $3$-smooth. When I said "the original question" I meant the first sentence of your question.

Comment: Wait my bad, you are asking the question for every prime $p$. Still, note that the question is at least as hard as bounding minimum prime gaps, so it shouldn't be easy at all. But maybe that was obvious :D

Comment: If I remember right , this was already asked here and I established a search limit with at least $p=10^9$

Comment: @Peter - It's not the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4645153/a-question-about-3-smooth-differences-between-primes even if they are related.